# Do automobiles leave less tracks when driving fast?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

A truck drives through the desert (or some other material where it can leave tracks), would its tracks be more shallow if it's driving fast?

Comment: Are you asking about a truck driving in desert sand?

Comment: material being one that tracks show up in. perhaps wet beach sand would be one example, or, dirt (tracks show up very well when driving in dirt), or on the moon for example (in desert sand tracks tend to collapse under gravity). just if speed traveled shapes tracks.

Comment: In my opinion, Wolphram jonny nailed it. I would accept his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going faster definitely leaves shallower tracks. I know this because as a young man I rode dirt bikes (motocross) a lot, when going through sand or soft silt if you went slower you would sink up in it, and usually lose speed and control. If you went very fast through it, you would stay more on top of it, leaving noticeably shallower tracks. For the tire to deform the surface, it needs to accelerate the top of the contact surface  until the surface's resistance equals the normal force. Acceleration requires a time factor. Going faster means the bottom of the tire has less time to accelerate the contact surface away from it.

Comment: Thanks. That was my intuition. Why I asked, the LRO images of the Apollo landing sites show very clear tracks close to where the LEM was, but some distance away the tracks disappear (even though they are on schematic drawings of the routes. ) I saw two explanations, 1) optical, possibly prioritized ideal lighting conditions for the nearby region and 2) when making longer excursions, they would travel faster, simply leaving less tracks for the reasons you mention.

Answer (score 2):

In principle they do, although I do not know how measurable is the effect at the range of speeds a car can go. In order to depress the soil the wheel makes a force, let us call it the normal. This normal force is independent of speed.Once the soil feel the force, it will move down a distance $d$ at some rate, for instance $d=1/2N/mt^2$ is the simplest idealization. But regardless of the exact form of $d$, time will be involved. The fastest you go the less time the force acts and the less d the soil moves down. In the limit of infinite speed there would be no tracks left.

Comment: I must admit, nice answer Wolphram.

Comment: Considering the circular geometry of the earth the normal force does depend on the speed of the bike (though it is quite  negligible)!